# Partition of the unit interval into uncountably many sets of full outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Is it possible to construct an uncountable partition $(A_\delta)_{\delta\in[0,1]}$ of the unit interval $[0,1]$ such that $\mu (A_\delta)=1$ for each $\delta\in[0,1]$? ($\mu$ stands for the outer Lebesgue measure.)

My motivation is as follows: Using Vitali sets of outer measure $1$, it is possible to construct a **countable** partition of $[0,1]$ with such properties. Indeed, one just need to put

$$A_\delta:=V+\delta \mod 1,\quad \delta\in\mathbb{Q},$$
where $V$ is the Vitali set of outer measure $1$.

My question is whether it is possible to construct an **uncountable** partition of $[0,1]$ with these properties.

Comment: You can even get continuum many pairwise disjoint sets of outer measure 1.  Bernstein sets will do the job.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169714 and in particular the answer from tomasz.

Comment: Very closely related: [Is there a maximum to the amount of disjoint non-measurable subsets of the unit interval with full outer measure?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119646/is-there-a-maximum-to-the-amount-of-disjoint-non-measurable-subsets-of-the-unit)